# How to update Minimum Qty 1 Allowed in Catalog sample products?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database

Right now in my products minimum quantity 0 is showing. How can i update in bulk products with 1 query ? i want to set minimum qty 1 in all sample products. and also Unchecked box (Using Config Settings). please look at screenshots and give me solution asap. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In admin -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory there is a tab called **Product Stock Options** You will find the **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** set its value to 1 and it will show at your admin -> catalog -> Manage products -> add/edit product -> inventory area.

[image]

Comment: No i don't want set from this option, i have already done from this option then Qty is start from 1 in frontend, i just want when user'll add to cart then he'll must enter QTY else 0 is considering by default is 1.